# phpmyadmin access denied error :invalid settings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

***i got this error***
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: which Operating System are you using, e.g linux, window or mac?

Comment: i use xampp on windows

Comment: look for config-db.php in your phpmyadmin directory, edit and file and update your db connection details.

Comment: i didn't find the folder in directory there is config.inc.php